# Use of [component].value vs value([component]) in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I have been advised that `value(x)` is preferable to using `x.value`, but this can cause issues with uninitialized variables when trying to store variable values like:

`initial_vals = {id(v): value(v) for v in m.component_data_objects(ctype=Var)}`

If any of the variables are not initialized, then this will cause a `ValueError` to be raised. Is this a credible use case for `x.value`, or is there a suggested alternative using `value(x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `exception=False` to the `value` function or the `__call__` method on `NumericValue` objects. This will suppress the `ValueError` and just return `None`.

On the other hand, if you know it's a variable, then it is absolutely safe to use the `.value` attribute. Params are the only other object (that I know of) with a `.value` attribute, but there is so much variation in how indexed Params can behave that it becomes preferable to just use the `value` function.